# Как выполнить появление элемента при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, прокрутка, блок

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы блок #top-panel появлялся только тогда, когда при прокрутке страницы блок #content достигал бы уже верхней части страницы? Благодарю за помощь!

```js
 $(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var distanceTop = $('#content').offset().top - $(window).height();
   if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
    $('#top-panel').animate({'top':'0px'},300);
   else
    $('#top-panel').stop(true).animate({'top':'-50px'},200);
  });
 });
```

```css
    #cover {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 900px;
     height: 100vh;
      background: green;
    }
    #content {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 3000px;
      background: blue;
    }
    #top-panel {
     position: fixed;
     overflow: hidden;
     top: -50px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     z-index: 5;
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cover" class="cover">
</div>
<div class="content" id="content">
</div>
<div id="top-panel" class="top-panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var distanceTop = $('#content').offset().top;
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var distanceTop = $('#content').offset().top;
   if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
    $('#top-panel').animate({'top':'0px'},300);
   else
    $('#top-panel').stop(true).animate({'top':'-50px'},200);
  });
 });
```

```css
#cover {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 900px;
     height: 100vh;
      background: green;
    }
    #content {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 3000px;
      background: blue;
    }
    #top-panel {
     position: fixed;
     overflow: hidden;
     top: -50px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     z-index: 5;
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cover" class="cover">
</div>
<div class="content" id="content">
</div>
<div id="top-panel" class="top-panel"></div>
```