# Как выполнить нечто при прокрутке страницы до интересующего блока

Tags: javascript, события, прокрутка

Тут есть близкая по смыслу штука, но не то [Как выполнить появление элемента при прокрутке страницы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635949/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Мне необходимо:

Выполнить событие цели Яндекс.Метрики при прокрутке страницы до интересующего элемента (мне конкретно до таблицы).

Про Событие цели Яндекс.Метрики - тут https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/objects/reachgoal.xml

Comment: При скролле у вас есть значение, сколько проскроллили, считаете положение по оси Y относительно верха страницы для вашей таблицы и с помощью значения высоты вьюпорта и нехитрой формулы можете отловить момент, когда элемент появился в видимой области.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант, который проверяет по скроллу пересечение видимых прямоугольников элементов

```html
<style>
  body{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  #container {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    height: 100vh; 
    overflow-x:hidden
  }

  .empty {
    height: 1000px;
  }

  .item {
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1000ms;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .item.show {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .item2.show {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  .item3.show {
    transform: translate(-100px,100px);
  }

  .item4.show {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item item1">SCROLL DOWN</div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="item item2">SCROLL DOWN</div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="item item3">SCROLL DOWN</div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="item item4">END</div>
</div>

<script>
  let container = document.getElementById('container');
  let containerRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  let trackElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];

  container.onscroll = function() {
    trackElements.forEach(el => {
      let r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (intersectRect(r, containerRect) && container.last !== el) {
        container.last = el;
        el.classList.add('show')
      }
    });
  }

  container.onscroll();

  function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
    return !(r2.left > r1.right || r2.right < r1.left || 
             r2.top > r1.bottom || r2.bottom < r1.top);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

В голову приходит такой костыль:
Высчитать, на каком расстоянии от верха находится Ваша таблица. Если все высоты заданы в пикселях, то можно просчитать заранее, если в vh, vw и тд, то придётся вышестоящим блокам давать айдишники, скриптом запрашивать их высоты и складывать их.

Далее прописываем функцию CheckScroll(), которая проверяет, на сколько страница прокручена (document.body.scrollTop), сравнивает её с высчитанным числом и при положительном результате выполняет нужные Вам действия.

Функцию эту вызываем при каждом изменении прокрутки:
windwo.onscroll = CheckScroll();

Comment: Только мне нужно, чтобы событие выполнилось при появлении таблицы один раз только. Как это реализовать?

Comment: два варианта
1 - при выполнении функции присваивать пустоту window.onscroll
2 - если не сработает, то добавить булиновую переменную, изначально равную false и тогда уже в CheckScroll первым делом спрашивать, равна ли она false. И присваивать ей true при выполнении функции, чтобы функция не отрабатывала снова.

Comment: У меня получилось.

Comment: У меня получилось. Но помогите как сделать, чтобы событие выполнялось только один раз. Сейчас при достижении таблицы с классом price-service событие происходит при каждом движении.

Comment: <script>
window.onscroll = function() {
  if ( checkViewport() ) {
alert("событие");
  }
  else { }
}
function checkViewport() {
         var $myElement = document.getElementById("price-service"),
             landmark = $myElement.getBoundingClientRect(),
             visibility = landmark.top + $myElement.scrollHeight > 0 && landmark.left + $myElement.scrollWidth > 0 && landmark.bottom - $myElement.scrollHeight < document.documentElement.clientHeight && landmark.right - $myElement.scrollWidth < document.documentElement.clientWidth
         return visibility

     }

</script>

Comment: Как так?

Вот так выводится сообщение о событии:
var AlreadyDone = false;
window.onscroll = function() {
  if ( !AlreadyDone && checkViewport() ) {
alert('Событие выполнено')
AlreadyDone = true
  }
}

Comment: А вот с событием Метрики вот так нет
var AlreadyDone = false;
window.onscroll = function() {
  if ( !AlreadyDone && checkViewport() ) {
yaCounter34962435.reachGoal('ceny'); return true
alert('Событие выполнено')
AlreadyDone = true
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Пишу новый ответ что бы код был легко читаемый

```
    <script>
      var AlreadyDone = false; //уже отработала? нет.
      var scrolllength = elemen1.style.height + element2.style.height + ... + 'px'; //сумма высот всех блоков над таблицей
      function checkViewport(){
        if (!AlreadyDone && document.body.scrollTop > scrolllength){ //если ещё не AlreadyDone и если Ваша прокрутка больше высчетанной высоты.
          //здесь код, который что-либо делает с таблицей
          AlreadyDone = true; //уже отработала? да. Теперь функция не будет отрабатывать снова.
        }
      }
      window.onscroll = checkViewport();
    </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только где я возьму сумму высот всех элементов над таблицей. Мне нужно просто событие когда верхняя строчка таблицы становится видимой в окне браузера.